# How to return formatted text from database into TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I have just a problem. 
I would like to have **formatted text** from database in my TinyMCE.

In the database I have code that looks like this:

```
 <p style="text-align: justify;"><strong>Zdrav&iacute;m</strong></p>
```

And **my script** is here:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 // Initialization TinyMCE (JS)
 tinyMCE.init({ ... });

 function loadText(text) {

    var editor = window.parent.tinyMCE.activeEditor;
    editor.setContent(text);
 }
 </script>

 // PHP
 $q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM article WHERE id = ".$_GET['id'].""); 
 while ($z = mysql_fetch_array($q)) { 
     $text = html_special_chars($z['content']);
 }
```

And if I try something like this:

```
<body onload = "loadText('hello');">
```

**That does works and content is loading into TinyMCE (without formatted)!**

But if I try something like this:

```
<body onload = "loadText(' <? echo $text; ?> ');">
```

**That doesn't work!**

What is going wrong?
I think, that problem will maybe in quotes and apostrophes.

**Other ideas and suggestions?**

Comment: View the HTML source and include the ouput in your question. The ouput of `$text` is most likely the source of your problems.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put your database text right into the element you use for the tinymce on  page creation. Lika a textarea. This would save some trouble:

```
<textarea id="my_editor"><? echo $text; ?></textarea>
```